# How can I calculate the area of a 5-arcminute grid cell in square kilometers, given a known latitude and longitude?

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, area

I am trying to compute the area of a 5-arcminute grid cell (coming from a global dataset) in square kilometers given a known longitude, latitude. I was able to compute the vertical length of the grid segment, but I am struggling to compute the horizontal segment. The lat-, long- are (approximately: 37.983810, 23.727539 for ellipsoidal earth from what I understand). Any ideas?

To be more specific : I wanted to use this dataset at a regional level, reproject it and clip it on the specific region without altering the original 5-arcminute grid size, as it includes certain values for that area. (e.g harvested area per 5-minute grid cell). I need to compute approximately how large these grid cells are for this specific region.

The dataset I am referring to is the GAEZ v4 2015 (for multiple harvested areas)

Comment: Do you want to compute the area with your own code instead of using some existing library or for example PostGIS?

Comment: For a spherical or ellipsoidal earth with what shape parameters? To what degree of accuracy?

Comment: I just did it, thank you for point that out!

Comment: I was currently trying to figure out how to do it in Arcgis Pro, but I don't mind using my own code too.

Comment: I think you should focus your question on ArcGIS Pro. You can always ask about where your stuck with your own code in a separate question that includes a code attempt.

Comment: Given two `arcpy.PointGeometry` objects, computing angle and distance is trivial.

Comment: Note that your rectangle isn't a rectangle -- It's actually a spheroidal trapezoid, so the area formula is `(a+b)*h*0.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate this precisely by taking your 5-arcminute "square" cell (in lat x long coordinates), projecting it to say UTM coordinates, and then querying the (ellipsoidal or planimetric) area in m^2 of the resultant trapezoid.

Or you can do it approximately as follows.

- 1 degree of latitude = 111.567km. This varies very slightly by latitude, but we'll ignore that.
- 5 arcminutes of latitude is
  1/12 of that, so 9.297km
- 5 arcminutes of longitude is similar, but
  multiplied by cos(latitude) if latitude is in radians, or
  cos(latitude/360 * 2 * 3.14159) if in degrees.
- So the area is about
  9.297^2 * cos(latitude/360 * 2 * 3.14159) square km.

The above neglects that the earth is an ellipsoid, so that there is actually slight variation of the metres per degree/minute of latitude as well. And it neglects the trapesoidal nature of the projected grid, approximating it as a square. But the variation over 5 arcminutes is pretty small except very close to the poles.

Comment: This was really helpful ! thank you very much!